# Remove and Redirect index.php from CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I got an old project and it has some bizarre issue. Its CodeIgniter project (version 2.X).

Google is indexing our URLs with index.php?. Below is an example

```
https://www.website.com/index.php?/my-seo-friendly-uri
```

I can see my pages from above url and with 2 more variants as below

```
https://www.website.com/index.php/my-seo-friendly-uri

https://www.website.com/my-seo-friendly-uri
```

We have used `https://www.website.com/my-seo-friendly-uri` throughout the site.

My question is how I can redirect `https://www.website.com/index.php?/my-seo-friendly-uri` and `https://www.website.com/index.php/my-seo-friendly-uri` to `https://www.website.com/my-seo-friendly-uri`?

**The thing I already did**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

This redirects `index.php` to normal URLs, but `index.php?` version of url is still not redirecting

In my `config.php`, I have the following settings

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: Use `[R=301,L]` on the `index.php?` version.

Comment: What is the code ?

Comment: Have you check for ```$config['enable_query_string']``` settings in config?

Comment: There is no such setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> https://www.example.com/index.php?/my-seo-friendly-uri
> ```

This URL contains a query string and so requires a slightly different rule in order to match it. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only (just `index.php` in this case). The query string is available in its own variable.

Add the following, before your existing directives (in addition to the directive that matches `/index.php/my-seo-friendly-url` - which is passed as *path-info*):

```
# Redirect URLs of the form "/index.php?/my-seo-friendly-uri"
# And "/?/my-seo-friendly-uri"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(/.*)
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ %1 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The query string is captured (2nd condition), and the backreference (`%1`) is used to construct the redirect.

The first condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is required in order to prevent a redirect loop, since you appear to be using the query string method to route the codeigniter URLs in the later rewrite. The `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is empty on the initial request, but set to "200" (as in 200 OK HTTP status) after the first successful rewrite.

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4+) is required to discard the original query string from the redirected request. If you are still on Apache 2.2 then append a `?` (empty query string) to the *substitution* string instead. ie. `%1?`

By making the match for `index.php` *optional* (ie. `^(index\.php)?$`) it will also canonicalise URLs that omit `index.php`, but still include the query string (that may or may not currently be a problem). eg. `/?/my-seo-friendly-uri`.

Note that this is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect (as is your existing redirect). Only change this to a 301 (permanent) redirect once you have confirmed it works OK. 301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic.

### Summary

Your `.htaccess` file should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Query string...
# Redirect URLs of the form "/index.php?/my-seo-friendly-uri"
# And "/?/my-seo-friendly-uri"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(/.*)
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ %1 [QSD,R=302,L]

# Path-Info...
# Redirect URLs of the form "/index.php/my-seo-friendly-uri"
# Also handles "/index.php" only
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 [R=302,L]

# CodeIgniter Front-controller
# (NB: Using query string method to pass the URL)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Additional notes...

- The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required.
- `(.*)` is the same as `^(.*)$` since regex is greedy by default.
- I've modified your existing path-info redirect (ie. `/index.php/foo`) to also redirect requests for `/index.php` only. This now requires an additional condition to avoid a redirect loop.
- Your CodeIgniter front-controller is using the query string method to pass `/my-seo-friendly-url` to the backend (as used in the question). However, you have set `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';` - which contradicts with this (although shouldn't necessarily be a problem). However, if you are using the `REQUEST_URI` method then you can remove the `?/$1` part from the end of the final `RewriteRule` *substitution* string. For example:

  For example, from this:

  ```
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
  ```

  To this:

  ```
  RewriteRule . index.php [L]
  ```

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite, it is redirecting like this 
`https://www.website.com/index.php?/my-seo-friendly-uri` -> `https://www.website.com/my-seo-friendly-uri?/my-seo-friendly-uri`

Comment: Sorry, you need the `QSD` flag on the `RewriteRule` to discard the original query string from the target URL. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now it works fot `index.php?` but not for `index.php`

Comment: "but not for `index.php`" - By that do you mean `/index.php` by itself and no path-info? I've modified your existing redirect to handle that scenario. What I've posted above should be all that's required - in addition to the directives you posted in the question (which was already redirecting URLs of the form `/index.php/foo`). I'm assuming you have no other directives in your `.htaccess` file that might otherwise be conflicting. I've updated my answer with a complete summary of exactly what your `.htaccess` file should look like.

Comment: Awesome, the last update did the trick. It is now working for both. I was not giving proper attention to identify both cases. I guess I need to learn lot.
Also, this is great in depth explanation. Again, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I copy index.php and .htacess from "\public" to "".
and edit "\index.php" to

```
require FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php';
```

modify "\app\config\app.php" as below

```
public string $indexPage = '';
```

then modify .htacess in "\public" and "" as

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

ServerSignature Off
```

It's work for me

Answer (score -1):

Use .htaccess................

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 <IfModule mod_php5.c>
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Working for `index.php?` but not for `index.php`

Comment: @sanjayojha The code above wouldn't "work for `index.php?`" (ie. it wouldn't canonicalise a request for `/index.php?/my-seo-friendly-url`) - it doesn't contain a redirect at all?!

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't answer the question. It makes no attempt to _remove_ `index.php` from the requested URL - in order to canonicalise incorrectly indexed URLs. The code here is simply a CodeIgniter front-controller (pretty much the same as the code already presented in the question).