# Rewriterule remove index.php from url for codeigniter causes too many redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

previously due to incorrect .htaccess logic, many of my http://example.com/path/ url is redirected to https://example.com/index.php?/path/

so there are many pages crawled by Google with https://example.com/index.php?/path/

I am using codeigniter, I do not want index.php in my URL, so I have rewrite rules that remove the index.php from the URL, so below is the rewrite rule for that.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But since there are many pages already crawled by Google with index.php in the URL, I want to redirect those URL to WITHOUT index.php but this will create conflict and create infinite redirect, one remove then one add, on and on.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php https://example.com%1? [R=302,L]
```

so when I access example.com/path/  this causes "Too many redirect" issues.

I am stuck with my logic here.

what should I do ?

Comment: Where did you place this, above or below the existing rewriting? (And what exactly are you trying to match with `(.*)` before `index.php` here?)

Comment: @CBroe Hi, I have put below the existing, but I tried moved to top, there's no difference. For the (.*), initially I thought there maybe some url example.com/path/index.php?/path2/ But then now I realized it always at the beginning, I guess that  (.*) before index.php  is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the answer here with the same issue, to avoid redirect loop, the key is to use

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
```

[Remove and Redirect index.php from CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60169302/remove-and-redirect-index-php-from-codeigniter)